# DB2 ROWNUM function throwing SQL0104

Tags: sql, db2, rownum

Getting reference from http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7705.rownum-function.aspx
, below is the error I get:

```
Select ROWNUM,* from tableA;
```

**SQL0206: Column ROWNUM not in specified tables**

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(),* from tableA;
```

**SQL0104: Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens FROM INTO**

What is the correct syntax to show row number in db2?

Comment: Which DB2 version (and platform) are you using? Did you try to read the DB2 manual instead of a reference from a third party site? `rownum` is an Oracle "function" and only available in DB2 9.7 with the "compatibility vector" enabled (and I think only for DB2/LUW)

Comment: What is it that you want the row number for?  `ROW_NUMBER()` will generate what amounts to a random number here.  `ROWNUM` isn't proof against things like reorgs, and shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @a_horse_with_no_name said, you have another error: if your `SELECT` list is just `*`, there can't be anything else in it. Try `Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(), tableA.* from tableA`